# Trying to view a product collection a user created and link_to/display in a separate view file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, link-to, listings

My users create collections and add listings to each collection. I have a main profile page for each user showing all collections created by that user. Now I want to link from each collection to an individual collection page showing all listings in that collection.

My user view file to show all collections:

```
<% @collections.each do |collection| %>
    <%= image_tag listing.image.url(:thumb) %>
    <%= link_to "#{collection.name}", shopcollected_path(collection_id: @collection) %>
<% end %>
```

When I click on my link I'm taken to the individual collection page (shopcollected.html.erb) just fine, but the listings for that collection aren't being recognized and the page is empty of listings. I know I'm missing one small part, but am stuck again on what that is. I'm still learning about retrieving objects from databases and linking.

My listings_controller:

```
def shopcollections
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @collections = Collection.where(user: User.find(params[:id])).order("created_at DESC")
end

def shopcollected
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @listings = Listing.where(collection: :collection_id)
end
```

My individual user 'shopcollected' view file:

```
<% @listings.each do |listing| %>
    <%= image_tag listing.image.url(:medium) %>
    <%= listing.name %>`
<% end %>
```

What am I missing? I believe I need to call all listings by collection, but in order to do so, where do I need to make a change in my code?

Comment: You can edit your question to fix errors like that (edit button is just below the tags). And we may need to see the view code for the shopcollected page as I don't see anything immediately wrong with the code so far.

Comment: Thanks @paul, I corrected my post above and added in my view file code. Thoughts?

Comment: Actually I believe I see the error. In your view code at the top, you have `shopcollected_path(collection_id: @collection)`, but the variable you're iterating over at that point is simply `collection` (without the at symbol). Change it accordingly and that should solve it, I believe.

Comment: okay did that. i now see my url: http://localhost:3000/shopcollected/9?collection_id=8 which tells me it's seeing my user shop #9 correctly and it's recognizing the collection id 8, however, no listings are presenting. It's still a blank page.

Comment: Can you verify that collection 8 has any listings? Also you appear to be doing this in the where clause: `.where(collection: :collection_id)`, but I assume that is a typo, as it should be `.where(collection: params[:collection_id])`, yes?

Comment: Yes! Thank you Paul, everything is working now.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. I'll post an actual answer containing what we talked about and you can go ahead and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as we discussed in the comments, there were two issues afflicting your application:

In the user view, when you were iterating over the collection of `@collections`, you were using the wrong variable inside the loop to refer to the current `Collection` object (specifically, `@collection` instead of `collection`). Should look like this:

```
<% @collections.each do |collection| %>
    <%= image_tag listing.image.url(:thumb) %>
    <%= link_to "#{collection.name}", shopcollected_path(collection_id: collection) %>
<% end %>
```

The other issue was in the `shopcollected` controller method. You simply forgot to include the `params` portion when attempting to access the `:collection_id` value from the form. It should look like this:

```
def shopcollected
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @listings = Listing.where(collection: params[:collection_id])
end
```

One minor unrelated suggestion, which will have no impact on performance but will slightly clean up your code and make it more Rails-y looking; in the case of the `shopcollections`, assuming you've set up the proper `belongs_to` and `has_many` associations in the models, there's a slightly shorter way of looking up the collections for the specific user, like so:

```
def shopcollections
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @collections = @user.collections.order("created_at DESC")
end
```

This will have the same affect as your previous version because Rails will load all the collections for **that** user, because you're invoking the `has_many` relationship method. Since most active record methods return a proxy, you can further invoke other methods like `order` which will now affect the filtration and ordering of the invoked `has_many` collection (in this case, the `Collection` objects). Hope that makes sense,

Comment: Yes, makes sense and works. So now if I want to link to this individual collection from somewhere else in my site, I'm using the same view file code, what needs to change in the link_to and controller file for this "other" page in order to define an :id somewhere so the [at]collections = Collection.includes(:listings) on my site page can identify the use associated with it? Does that make sense?

Comment: @amyep It depends how you're storing and passing around the user id. Is this meant to be for the currently logged in user?

Comment: No, this is for anyone browsing the site. I currently have defined: [at]user = User.where(collection: params[:collection_id]), and then in my link_to I have shopcollected_path(collection). So right now when I click on a collection, I see in the url /shopcollected/15, so it's seeing and linking the collection correctly, just not pulling the user id and listings yet.

Comment: @amyep Ok maybe I misunderstood your original comment-question. So going back to what you said before: *"...if I want to link to this individual collection from somewhere else in my site..."*, what is the use-case in this scenario? Meaning, why would / what would make this individual collection be linked on another page?

Comment: Yes, sorry, quick explanation: my users are sellers. They create collections of listings. People can shop from the home page that shows all listings from all sellers. The next tab is Collections where people can shop by collection and I'm displaying the first 3 images in that collection as a teaser. So each of these collection teasers should link to the individual collection page I set up.

Comment: @amyep Ok that clears things up a lot more. But I'm still not clear on the current problem. You mentioned originally wanting to "identify the [user] associated with it" (the collection); based on your last comment, if you're displaying a list of collections, then each collection "knows" to which `User` it belongs (something like`collection.user` which you can access when you're iterating through the collections). Is that what you wanted to know?